# iOS default System Font is free or Payable?

Tags: ios, fonts

Am using `UIFont systemFontOfSize:, UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:` this code for  having default System Font usage throughout the app.

Is iOS default system font is payable or free? I have seen in some sites that default font is always free. But the Client is saying that even if its default font its payable. We are not using any Custom font files in our app.

Kindly suggest Free fonts that we can use in our iOS Apps. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can use any of the fonts built in to iOS without payment

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a business and legal concern, not a coding issue.

Comment: Did you finally found the answer or was the provided documentation helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find the answer below:

> E. Fonts. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, you may
>   use the fonts included with the Apple Software to display and print
>   content while running the Apple Software; however, you may only embed
>   fonts in content if that is permitted by the embedding restrictions
>   accompanying the font in question. These embedding restrictions can be
>   found in the Font Book/Preview/Show Font Info panel.

http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macOS1012.pdf

Taken from this question:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7493969

Comment: Thanks a lot, your document helped a lot. But i haven't found any free fonts because  in FontBook, most of the fonts has "Embedding Restrictions" and nowhere mentioned about "What are all the embedding restrictions". Raised a query to Apple but they are telling to raise a query in Forum. Trying to use "Google Free Fonts" but Apple Developer Support is not ensuring those are free if we used in iOS